# How can I execute an external Windows command and instantly return in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl

I've tried using system() with fork(), tried exec(), and am still not getting what I need.

I want to write a Perl script which executes, let's say, a different Perl script five times in a row (sending it different parameter values), but I have it run concurrently. I realize I could turn my script into a .pm file and reference it, but I'd prefer to keep the child script independent of the parent...

- system() works, but executes the
  commands consecutively (makes sense
  per documentation)
- exec() doesn’t work - it only executes
  the first method (makes sense per
  doc)
- I added a fork() to the child Perl
  script and then tried using system()
- this did not work either.
- backtick command ' documents says it
  works the same as system()...

Isn't there a simple way in Perl (I'm using Windows XP) to execute a process, and not care about the return values or anything and just continue on into the next line of the parent script?

Comment: Post some code, so we can see what didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Windows, you can give the super-secret `1` flag to the system, IIRC.

```
system 1, @cmd;
```

A Google search for this question on PerlMonks gives: *[Start an MS window in the background from a Perl script](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=639814)*

Comment: this worked awesome. Thanks. First time using perl, this works great. thanks to everyone else who replied after my comment

Comment: @dferraro => welcome to the magical land of Perl, hope you enjoy your stay.  In general, I would recommend that you stay away from operating system specific solutions if a more general solution exists.  You never know when you will need the script to work on an unforeseen platform.

Comment: thanks for the welcome... I'd like to run away like hell now. I still haven't seen a single line of perl that didn't take me 5 minutes to overstand ;)

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this (fork in the parent, exec in the child):

```
for my $cmd qw(command1 command2 command3) {
    exec $cmd unless fork
}
```

The way that `exec $cmd unless fork` works is that `fork` will return a true value in the parent (the process id) and will return a false value in the child, thus `exec $cmd` only gets run if `fork` returns false (aka, in the child).

Or if you want to keep tabs on the process as it runs concurrently:

```
my @procs;

for my $cmd qw(cmd1 cmd2 cmd3) {

    open my $handle, '-|', $cmd or die $!;

    push @procs, $handle;
}
```

Then you can read from an element of `@procs` if you need to.

Or take a look at one of the many CPAN modules, like `Forks::Super` that handle the details of fork management.

Comment: Just be aware that fork() on Windows has some complications, and since the open is simply a fork under the covers, you'll see them there, too.

Answer (score 4):

A very lightweight approach.

Windows:

```
foreach my $cmd (@cmds)
{
    `start $cmd`;
}
```

Unix:

```
foreach my $cmd (@cmds)
{
    `$cmd &`;
}
```

Comment: I did try this cause it looked simple too, but it didnt open any console windows and then it hung on the last execution... ?

Comment: Generally, I like to avoid backticks just to avoid the shell.  Especially on Windows where $cmd may have spaces in it.

Answer (score 3):

A module is overkill for this job. You want to `fork` to create a new process and then `exec` to run a command in the new process. To run five commands, you need something like:

```
 for (my $i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
     if (fork() == 0) {
         exec($command[$i]);   # Runs command and doesn't return
     }
 }
```

Comment: A module is not overkill if you want cross-platform behaviour that hides all the platform-specific behaviour that fork emulation on Windows brings.  Hiding complexity behind a (hopefully) simple interface is one of the purposes of modules.

Comment: If you have version 5.8 or later, there is nothing wrong with fork and exec on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fork in the parent, and then exec in the new process. It goes like this, assuming A is the original script, and B is the one you want to do 5 times:

```
                A1
fork in A1   -> A1 A2
exec B in A2 -> A1 B2
fork in A1   -> A1 A3 B2
exec B in A3 -> A1 B3 B2
```

etc.

Comment: How can I fork in the parent? fork doesn't take params, so How do I tell it which command to execute...

Comment: You first call [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html).  That duplicate the process as shown, then `fork` returns twice.  You then use the return value to determine which process you're in.  If it's non-zero, it's the parent; if 0, then the child.  Then, in the child, you call [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html).  Eric provided a concise example.